# mORMot 1.18 doesn't invalidate session_signature after logout? is this the default behaviour?

Tags: web-application, session-management, token

On a website which uses mORMot 1.18 every request made by an authenticated user is in this format:

`../search_items?session_signature=0000004C000F6DD02E24541C` as reported within the [framework docs](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html)

> Here is typical signature to access the root URL
>
> `root?session_signature=0000004C000F6BE365D8D454`
>
> In this case, 0000004C is the Session ID, 000F6BE3 is the client time
> stamp (aka nonce), and 65D8D454 is the signature, checked by the
> following Delphi expression:
>
> `(crc32(crc32(fPrivateSaltHash,PTimeStamp,8),pointer(aURL),aURLlength)=aSignature);`
>
> For instance, a RESTful GET of the TSQLRecordPeople table with RowID=6
> will have the following URI:
>
> `root/People/6?session_signature=0000004C000F6DD02E24541C`

I tried the following:

1. authenticate as **userA**, send a request which shows sensitive content. Save `session_signature=A` value.
2. perform the logout
3. login again as **userA** in order to have a new `session_signature=B` which shoud invalidate the first one
4. logout and send again the request with the `session_signature=A`
5. the old `session_signature` value worked.

Is this the default behavior of mORMot or is a misconfiguration? Should I consider it a session management misconfiguration since the value of session_signature is not invalidated?